# Angular custom filter for European currency format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Hello everyone here is short brief of my question regarding custom currency, i am looking for European currency format just like as :

`Input : 123456789.22`

`Output : 123 456 789,22`

I am looking for the logic to implement into my custom filter.

Here is my custom filter and code format.

```
myApp.filter('myCurrency', function() {
      return function(nStr) {   
        if (nStr) {
          // return European currency format
        }     
      }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note : Posting for others to share knowledge.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.filter('myCurrency', function() {
  return function(nStr) {   
    if (nStr) {
      nStr += '';
      x = nStr.split('.');
      x1 = x[0];
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ' ' + '$2');
      }
      return x1 + x2;
    }    
  }
})


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> You typed : {{name | myCurrency}}!
</div>
```

Comment: Why don you use the filter number:2 ?..it work ok for me... somthing like: <span data-ng-bind="item.bestPartner.price|number:2"></span>€

Comment: because i want the custom format just like as provided in question, in format of space after three number and comma where decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

follow this:
http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/format-text-using-angularjs-currency-filter.htm

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;">
    <div ng-app>
        <p>
            <label>Enter a number</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="bid" />
        </p>

        <p> {{ bid | currency : "€"}} </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank, i knew this already, this is not exact according to question, if i enter `111111111.22 ` answer should be `111 111 111,22 `